# git bash says I am on a deleted branch (within a repository that was deleted)

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I am new to both github concepts and utilising git bash bash for navigation.

When I start git bash, I see

`User@DESKTOP-username MINGW64 ~ (branchname)`

But branch `branchname` has been deleted. In fact, I deleted (via browser UI) the entire repository that this branch was created in.

I tried

`git checkout branchname`
but this returns

```
error: pathspec 'branchname' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on here? Even better, point me to something from which I may develop a better understanding of.

Comment: What does `git for-each-ref | grep branchname` print? The one you deleted via browser UI was in the remote repository. The one in the local repository should still be there. Besides, what concerns me is the `~` ahead of `(branchname)`. What is the path of the current directory? It's not proper to initialize the home directory as a git repository.

Comment: ```git for-each-ref | grep branchname``` has no output.

The path for my current directory is
```/c/Users/user```

More info:

I could perform a change of directory via ```cd <directory>```
and I get
User@DESKTOP-username MINGW64 ~<directory> (branchname)

Comment: Try `echo $PS1` and see what's in the position of `branchname`.

Comment: It returns
```echo $PS1```
returns
```$ echo $PS1
\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$```

Comment: `(branchname)` is generated by `__git_ps1`. How about `git for-each-ref`? Does it print anything related with `branchname`?

Comment: ```git for-each-ref````
has no output.

a newline 
like
```User@DESKTOP-username MINGW64 ~<directory> (branch)``` shows

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228363/discussion-between-elpiekay-and-physkid).

Comment: @ElpieKay
Tremendously kind and helpful to solve the issue I was facing.